# Re-mounting a live OS filesystem

Tags: linux, command-line, filesystems, liveusb, fstab

I'm running Debian live on a USB flash storage device and I accidentally removed the drive.

Now I keep getting input/output errors:
`bash:     /usr/bin/xyz: Input/output error`.

- The drive originally mounted as: `/dev/sdb1`.
- But now it's auto-mounting as: `/dev/sdc1`.

How do I get it to mount as: `/dev/sdb1` again, so I can avoid a reboot?

FYI: The device is identifiable as:
`/dev/disk/by-label/Debian\x20Live`.

Comment: Did you try the normal `mount` command? (`sudo mount /dev/disk/by-label/Debian\x20Live`) Alternatively, if you have not changed anything on your host and it is really just a life system, you normally can safely turn it off or use the [SysRq keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Uses).

Comment: @SimonA.Eugster `mount: can't find Debian\x20Live in /etc/fstab`.

Comment: Sorry; you also have to give the target path `/dev/sdb1` (and maybe more parameters) after the mount path.

Comment: @SimonA.Eugster Okay, I think we're getting somewhere, but now: `mount: mount point /dev/sdb1 does not exist`.

Comment: `sudo mkdir /dev/sdb1` then because the directory is missing :)

Comment: @SimonA.Eugster hmm; I actually did try that. Now it's `mount: special device Debian\x20Live does not exist`. Also tried escaping the `\x20`, which returned no errors, yet `fdisk -l` shows no changes.

Comment: Forget the crap I wrote before, my brain was on standby. `/dev/sdb1` is not the mount point of the drive but the device descriptor which has to be mounted to a directory like `/mnt/sdb1` or `/` or alike (`/etc/fstab` could give you some hints), whatever it was before. But probably that is not enough on a live system.

Comment: @SimonA.Eugster Aha. No worries mate. I thought something like that might be the case. Currently neither `sdb*` nor `sdc*` appear in `/etc/fstab` (in fact it's looking quite bare). Although, `/dev/sdc*` is reported by `fdisk -l`. Do you have any other suggestions? I'm reading up on all things `udev` and `fstab` but my brain is slowly turning to mush.

Comment: Can you start another PC with the same live system and check how the disk is mounted there? `mount` should provide you with the relevant information.

Comment: @SimonA.Eugster Yep. Okay, I have it running on a second device. What information exactly, am i looking for? If you can give an example, I can make sure I get the relevant details. Cheers mate; much appreciated.

Comment: Mainly the difference between the two machines, some mount points will be missing. It might also be a good idea to join some IRC channel like [#linux on freenode](https://freenode.linux.community/) and ask there for help, that would most likely be faster.